# Applied logic challenge problem

Tags: logical-deduction, computer-puzzle

You must determine what can be concluded from the 60 true statements below. The numbers in each statement represent binary values (`true` / `false`, `1` / `0`), or attributes that either are present or are not present.

For example, in words, Statement 1 reads:
*If 3 is true and 29 is true then 13 is false.*

> **Statement 1:** if `3` and `29` then not `13`
>   **Statement 2:** if (`27` and `9`) or (`14` and not `10`) then `4`
>   **Statement 3:** if `14` and `28` then not `6`
>   **Statement 4:** if (`2` and `16`) or (`27` and not `18`) then `24`
>   **Statement 5:** if `14` and `29` then `11`
>   **Statement 6:** if `7` and `11` and not `10` then `21`
>   **Statement 7:** if `30` and `3` and not `12` then `11`
>   **Statement 8:** if `3` and `7` and not `1` then `23`
>   **Statement 9:** if (`10` and `1`) or (`23` and not `16`) then `27`
>   **Statement 10:** if `19` and `9` then not `27`
>   **Statement 11:** if `26` and `8` then not `5`
>   **Statement 12:** if `10` or `19` then not `13`
>   **Statement 13:** if (`1` and `6`) or (`9` and not `13`) then `25`
>   **Statement 14:** if `11` and `3` and not `4` then `17`
>   **Statement 15:** if `28` or `16` then `8`
>   **Statement 16:** if (`2` and `7`) or (`14` and not `13`) then `20`
>   **Statement 17:** if `27` and `26` then `15`
>   **Statement 18:** if `27` or `7` then `4`
>   **Statement 19:** if `30` and `11` and not `24` then `28`
>   **Statement 20:** if `27` and `10` and not `30` then `29`
>   **Statement 21:** if `27` and `9` and not `24` then `4`
>   **Statement 22:** if `4` and `28` then `15`
>   **Statement 23:** if `16` or `23` then not `25`
>   **Statement 24:** if `20` and `17` then `11`
>   **Statement 25:** if `6` or `28` then `30`
>   **Statement 26:** if (`5` and `18`) or (`6` and not `26`) then `16`
>   **Statement 27:** if `23` or `21` then `20`
>   **Statement 28:** if `25` or `6` then `20`
>   **Statement 29:** if `29` and `8` and not `23` then `7`
>   **Statement 30:** if `9` or `18` then `16`
>   **Statement 31:** if `12` and `11` and not `24` then `2`
>   **Statement 32:** if `6` and `24` then not `15`
>   **Statement 33:** if `9` or `5` then not `25`
>   **Statement 34:** if `17` and `8` and not `26` then `22`
>   **Statement 35:** if `15` and `1` then `11`
>   **Statement 36:** if `28` and `5` then `2`
>   **Statement 37:** if `2` and `9` and not `12` then `6`
>   **Statement 38:** if `26` and `14` then `22`
>   **Statement 39:** if `12` or `16` then `13`
>   **Statement 40:** if `9` and `8` then `16`
>   **Statement 41:** if `8` and `15` then not `27`
>   **Statement 42:** if `18` or `7` then `25`
>   **Statement 43:** if `30` and `2` then not `17`
>   **Statement 44:** if `23` and `4` then not `9`
>   **Statement 45:** if `17` and `11` and not `18` then `29`
>   **Statement 46:** if `10` and `5` then not `28`
>   **Statement 47:** if `12` and `18` and not `9` then `23`
>   **Statement 48:** if `9` and `17` then not `18`
>   **Statement 49:** if `21` or `5` then not `22`
>   **Statement 50:** if (`21` and `16`) or (`19` and not `17`) then `25`
>   **Statement 51:** if `13` or `24` then not `6`
>   **Statement 52:** if `1` and `18` and not `2` then `30`
>   **Statement 53:** if `8` and `30` and not `1` then `9`
>   **Statement 54:** if `10` and `28` then `6`
>   **Statement 55:** if `13` or `12` then not `21`
>   **Statement 56:** if `1` and `22` and not `20` then `23`
>   **Statement 57:** if (`3` and `30`) or (`12` and not `13`) then `23`
>   **Statement 58:** if `8` or `11` then `14`
>   **Statement 59:** if (`27` and `16`) or (`17` and not `28`) then `21`
>   **Statement 60:** if (`27` and `16`) or (`22` and not `14`) then `28`

Comment: Hi there, what is the source of this puzzle?

Comment: All 60 statements are true.  Of course the attributes within each statement may be true or false as noted.  This is a problem of my own devising and the solution is very concise.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that this is a puzzle of yours.

Comment: Please re-read the problem.  The numbers within each statement refer to binary values or attributes and not statement numbers.

Comment: so 27 is like b[27].? and the array goes from 1..30? is the system consistent, or are we working this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We can see that 18 is definitely False. There are many solutions that satisfy all the requirements. But other numbers can go either way, that is, they can all be either true or false in different solutions.

This can be seen as follows:

> Assume 18 is True
>  Then (S30) means that 16 is True
>  And (S42) means that 25 is True
>  And (S23) means that 25 is False - whoops!
>  Therefore 18 is False (by contradiction)

I'm not sure what else we're looking for. It's possible to do a similar sort of thing for other numbers:

> E.g. if you start with all falses, except 6, and use the below methodology, you will find a solution in which 6 is false. However, deeper searching yields a stable solution of (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1) which has 6 equal to True.

I found 1486 solutions as follows:

1. Set all the values to 0
2. Change {0,1,2,3} of the values to 1 (all possible combinations)
3. Run all the statements, adjusting the outputs if necessary (see below).
4. Repeat 3 until stability is reached or until I've iterated 60 times without reaching stability.
5. Save all stable solutions (discarding any repeated solutions).

*[Notes for point 3: All statements are "if X then Y". So if X is true and Y is false, then I adjust the variable in Y and rerun.
Notes for point 4: Obviously, stability might be found later than this in principle. I haven't yet checked, but I suspect that they are mostly cycling.]*

In this situation:

> Starting with all false, there is a solution immediately (all false).
>  Starting with 1 true, there are 29 solutions (only 17=True doesn't yield a stable solution immediately).
>  Starting with 2 trues, there are 253 solutions.
>  Starting with 3 trues, there are 1203 solutions.
>  So, I have found a total of 1203 solutions.
>  Starting on the other end (with all trues and adjusting {0,1,2,3} to false yields no stable solutions with this method.

Here's 31 consistent solutions showing how each other number can be True:

> ```
> (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
> (1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
> (0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
> (0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
> (0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
> (0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
> (0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
> (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1) (Bonus one from setting 29 and 30 to True)
> (0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
> (0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
> (0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
> (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
> (0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
> (0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)
> (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
> (0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
> (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
> (0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
> (0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
> (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
> (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
> (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
> (0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1)
> (0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)
> (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
> (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
> (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
> (0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)
> (0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1)
> (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
> (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
> ```

Comment: Congratulations, Dr. Xorile, you have solved this correctly.  Your hard work has paid off here.  I plan on posting another problem that will look similar but will have an interesting twist.

Answer (score 3):

Let's try, is it correct that

> all numbers are **false**

because

> if you look at the statements, all of them are in a form of "if X then Y" which is only wrong when both X is true and Y is false. By setting all numbers are false, all X will be false hence all statements will be automatically true.

Comment: that's a really clever solution, and is definitely correct, +1 from me. Although it probably isn't the intended answer.

Comment: You have found 1 combination of numbers (all false) that satisfy all statements.  However that cannot be the conclusion to be derived if there are other combinations of numbers (some false, some true) that also satisfy all the statements.